# GitHub Action - Create matrix from files with wildcard

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to get a mono-repo a little more streamlined, and I'm not ready to break it apart.

There are roughly 12 unit test projects, and I'm adding integration test projects that require a docker image to run (hosting sql, localstack, etc.).

The folder structure looks something like this:

```
src/
-> Foo/...
tests/
-> Foo/
   -> Foo.UnitTests/Foo.UnitTests.csproj
   -> Foo.IntegrationTests/Foo.IntegrationTests.csproj
-> Bar/
   -> Bar.UnitTests/Bar.UnitTests.csproj
   -> Bar.IntegrationTests/Bar.IntegrationTests.csproj
...
```

I want to run the UnitTests and IntegrationTests separately, and I don't want to have anything hardcoded because other developers might not remember to add to the list if / when a new test project is created.

Ideally, `dotnet test` would support adding a csproj filter by regex, but it does not.  The normal filter parameter won't work because the namespaces aren't consistent enough.

So I am trying to do something like this:

```
  unit-test-list:
    name: unit-test-list
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      matrix: ${{ steps.set-matrix.outputs.matrix }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - id: set-matrix
        run: echo "name=matrix::$(ls ./**/*.UnitTests.csproj | jq -R -s -c 'split("\n")[:-1]')" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

  unit-test: 
    name: unit-test 
    needs: [build,unit-test-list]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest 
    strategy: 
      fail-fast: true 
      matrix: 
        csproj: ${{ fromJson(needs.unit-test-list.outputs.matrix) }}
    steps: 
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2 
    - name: Setup .NET 
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1 
      with: 
        dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_VERSION }} 
    - name: Install dependencies 
      run: dotnet restore 
    - name: Run *.UnitTests 
      run: dotnet test ${{ matrix.csproj }} --no-restore --verbosity quiet
```

My issue is `ls ./**/*.UnitTests.csproj`.  No matter what I try, the attempt to generate the list always fails with a message such as `ls: cannot access './**/*.UnitTests.csproj': No such file or directory`.

I've tried with different cases and search strings.  When I hard code a path like this, the error goes away but the unit-test job fails with an error that it received an empty string:
`echo "name=matrix::$(ls ./tests/Foo/Foo.UnitTests/Foo.UnitTests.csproj | jq -R -s -c 'split("\n")[:-1]')" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT`

Error:
`Build and Test Solution: .github#L1 Error when evaluating 'strategy' for job 'unit-test'. .github/workflows/on-pull-request.yml (Line: 44, Col: 17): Error parsing fromJson,.github/workflows/on-pull-request.yml (Line: 44, Col: 17): Error reading JToken from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0.,.github/workflows/on-pull-request.yml (Line: 44, Col: 17): Unexpected value ''`

If I hard code the `unit-test` matrix to `csproj: ["./tests/Foo/Foo.UnitTests/Foo.UnitTests.csproj","./tests/Bar/Bar.UnitTests/Bar.UnitTests.csproj"]` then it works just fine, so I know the problem is in the list generation code.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had the syntax for setting the matrix incorrect.

Here's what it should be: `run: echo "matrix=$(ls ./tests/*/*/*.UnitTests.csproj | jq -R -s -c 'split("\n")[:-1]')" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"`